# Java Swing change to JButton background color does not show

Tags: java, swing

The following program code is a boiled down version of my application. The changes to
the background color in lines 45, 47,48 are not shown though the print command show
that they have been effected.

As you see, I have tried
several repaint, pack etc commands without success. What am I missing?

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonColor extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public int Lifecols, Liferows;
    private JPanel zellPanel,FertigPanel;
    private JButton ChosenB;
    public JButton[][]  zellen;
    
    ButtonColor(){
    this.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        setCellPanel(10,10);
        FertigPanel = new JPanel();
    ChosenB  = new JButton("Auswahl bestätigen");
    ChosenB.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
    ChosenB.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 50));
    ChosenB.addActionListener(this);
    FertigPanel.add(ChosenB);
       getContentPane().add(zellPanel);
       add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,20)));
       getContentPane().add(FertigPanel);
       add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
       pack();
       repaint();
       setVisible ( true);}
    
    public void setCellPanel(int Lifecols,int Liferows){
    JButton zelle;
    zellPanel = new JPanel();
    zellPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(Liferows, Lifecols));
    zellPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1100, 1100));
        zellen = new   JButton[Liferows][Lifecols];
     for (int rowIndex=0; rowIndex< Liferows; rowIndex++)
        { for (int colIndex =0; colIndex < Lifecols; colIndex++)
          {zellen[rowIndex][colIndex] =  new JButton();
           zellen[rowIndex][colIndex].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        zellPanel.add(zellen[rowIndex][colIndex]);
          }}
     return;}
    public void  SetBlinker1(){
    System.out.println(zellen[3][3].getBackground());
    zellen[3][3].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    System.out.println(zellen[3][3].getBackground());
        zellen[3][4].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    zellen[3][5].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    zellen[3][3].repaint();
    zellPanel.repaint();
    getContentPane().repaint();
    pack();
    return;}
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if (e.getSource() == ChosenB) {
        setCellPanel(10,10);
        SetBlinker1();
        pack();
        revalidate();
        repaint();
        return;
    }}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ButtonColor();
    }}
```

Comment: Variable/field names should begin in lowercase so they don't get confused with class names, which start in uppercase.

Comment: Your code's indentation leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: Don't call `setCellPanel` in `actionPerformed` and call `setOpaque(true)` in `setCellPanel`.

Comment: `JButton` is a complex component, the "background" doesn't always effect the platform specific rendering (border) - see [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065691/how-to-set-the-background-color-of-a-jbutton-on-the-mac-os)

Comment: the problem definitively is calling `setCellPanel` inside `actionPerformed` as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77775127/java-swing-change-to-jbutton-background-color-does-not-show#comment137114704_77775127) by Jeff - this is creating a new matrix of buttons, assigning it to `zellen`, and adding these buttons to a new panel which is not being displayed. The background of the new buttons is changed, but these are not being displayed. BTW you must work on your indentation - posted code is very hard to read! BTW-2 `setOpaque(true)` is the default... no need to call it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On most platforms, `JButton` renders a platform specific style button.  This tends to ignore the `background` property.

I would suggest making sure that the button is opaque and change the border used by the button...

```
zellen[rowIndex][colIndex].setOpaque(true);
zellen[rowIndex][colIndex].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
```

This will, in most cases, ensure that you've overridden the "platform stylings".

[image]

*nb: I resized the frame to make the image smaller*

You're next problem is, you're calling `setCellPanel(10, 10);` in your `actionPerformed` method.  This is causing all sorts of issues.  If you MUST do this, first remove all the pre-existing buttons from the `zellPanel`, but, I'd just not call it at all...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == ChosenB) {
        SetBlinker1();
    }
}
```

I would also recommend taking a look at [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-contents.html).  It will make it easier for you to read/understand other peoples code and for other's to read/understand yours.

Comment: Also note that there is no need for any of the "repaint" or "pack" logic in the "SetBlinker1" method. A Swing component will automatically repaint itself when a property of the component (i.e. the background) is changed.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies that put me on the right track. Incorporating your suggestions and a bit more I came up with a very satisfactory solution. I blatantly ignored code conventions so far. Following your reminders I will change this.